# How to shorten MongoDB ObjectId and use it in Mongoose schema

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, objectid

I am looking for a way to shorten the ObjectID generated by the MongoDB database, and I am aware of some of the existing library like 'shortid''short-mongo-id'

However, my problem is that I wish to create a new 'shortID' field in the mongoose schema for every document that exists in the collection, and this new field should be unique and ideally the truncated version of the ObjectId attached to the document.
Like such:

```
var subjectSchema = new Schema({

    shortID: {required: true, unique: true}, 
    //must be unique to each document and is same everytime server restarts

    Sex: {type: String, enum: enumSex},
    Diagnosis: String,
    Projects:[projectPerSubjectSchema]
});
```

The 'shortid' https://www.npmjs.com/package/shortid library works good and does generate unique id, but, it generates different id every time server restarts, which is not what I want.

Another library I tried 'short-mongo-id' https://www.npmjs.com/package/short-mongo-id was able to convert ObjectId into a truncated version of unique ID string, however, I'm not sure how to use it in creating a schema. I've tried:

```
ID: {type: String, 'default': shortid((this.ObjectId).valueOf()), unique: true}
```

to try and get the document's ObjectId using this.ObjectId, stringify it with valueOf(), but the terminal shows:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'valueOf' of undefined
```

All of the code are done in Node.JS and I am very new to both NodeJS and MongoDB, so please correct me if I am making some major errors with the code provided above. Thanks in advance!

Comment: You're going to need to implement a [custom type](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/customschematypes.html). But going one step back: why can't you use regular `ObjectId`'s?

Comment: I figured that it will make the query for information on a particular object difficult as the users will need to type in long IDs, and URL looks very messy. I could be wrong, if there's better way of doing the query based on ObjectId easily, please let me know

Comment: Perhaps there's a way to not have to bother the user with id's at all? Even if they are short, id's of any form are generally not great for regular people to have to handle.

Comment: If the Ids are short, you might face the issue of duplicate Ids pretty soon....   On the other hand, there are well known ways of avoiding using Ids for queries....

Answer (score 1):

The shortid module should work for what you need, you just need to save the shortId as normal String field, and make sure a new code is generated before saving, like this (inside mongoose schema definition):

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose')
const shortid = require('shortid')
const Schema = mongoose.Schema
const schema = new Schema({
  _shortId: {
    type: String,
    unique: true
  },
  ... // other fields...
})
// This is for checking if the document already have a _shortId, 
// so you don't replace it with a new code
schema.pre('save', function (next) {
  let doc = this

  if (!this._shortId) { 
    addShortId(doc, next)
  } 
})

function addShortId (doc, next) {
  let newShortId = shortid.generate()
  doc.constructor.findOne({_shortId: newShortId}).then((docRes) => {
    if (docRes) {
      addShortId(doc, next)
    } else {
      doc._shortId = newCode
      next()
    }
  }, (err) => {
    next(err)
  })
}
```

If you want to insert a _showId for all the existing documents, you just need a `forEach` and save the model again, this is how I'm doing (using https://github.com/JMPerez/promise-throttle, cause it's a huge collection, calling save() all at once would slow down the server) :

```
XXXXX.find({ '_shortId': { '$exists': false } }).then((data) => {
  var promiseThrottle = new PromiseThrottle({
    requestsPerSecond: 50,
    promiseImplementation: Promise
  })
  var i = 1
  data.forEach(element => {
  var myFunction = function (j) {
    return element.save()
  }
  promiseThrottle.add(myFunction.bind(this, i++)).then(ss => {
    console.log('done ' + ss._shortId)
  })
})
```

Some of this code is adapted from: https://github.com/dylang/shortid/issues/65